# Dynamically show Activity as dialog

Tags: android

I have an Activity that I have already implemented sometime ago.

It involves around making a in app purchase, so all the logic is relatively self contained. it doesn't need to care about anything else.

Now, i wish to make that Activity to optionally show up in a dialog in some other activity. Is there a quick way to do that? I still need to keep the old behavior however, where the activity show up as a regular screen.

So is there someway that I could launch the activity with that make it show up as a dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant show activity as dialog.

Your options are:

1: Open the other activity with some boolean extra like "showDialog", true

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("showDialog", true);
```

and in the other activity in (for example) onCreate:

```
Boolean showDialog = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("showDialog");
if (showDialog) {
    // Code to show dialog
}
```

2: Create a DialogFragment and show it in your original activity. This custom DialogFragment you can use on both activities

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

Probably your cleanest option depending on how complex your Activity is, is to create a new DialogFragment based on your current activity.

A DialogFragment is basically a Fragment, so has a relatively similar set of lifecycle callbacks to your Activity so it shouldn't be too difficult to re-work as a DialogFragment.

If the in-app purchase framework has specific callback requirements with an Activity then you will need to take that into account.

Another separate option would be to mock the appearance of a Dialog, by creating an Activity that may be transparent around the border of the main content.

Answer (score 0):

Just Inflate the layout one button click on onCreate Method.
WhAT I WILL SUGGEST IS try alert box and in place of normal layout inflate you activity layout .
these might help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to apply a dialog theme to the activity:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" />
```

Or in the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
}
```

You can customize parameters of the theme in `styles.xml`, e.g. dim enabled/disabled, click outside behavior.

The crucial point is to perform `setTheme()` before `super.onCreate()`, because `Theme` is immutable, once set through `super.onCreate()` it cannot be mutated later.